# How to remove/replace Google Ads div with a custom div

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-ads-api, adsense, google-ad-manager

I'm building a Chrome extension for educational purposes that removes/replaces a GoogleAds div with my custom div.

How do I locate the google-ad divs? Is there a specific id or class associated with it?

This is how I'm injecting my code into the website:--

**content-script.js**

```
var div=document.createElement("div"); // is there any specific divID associated with it?
document.body.appendChild(div); 
div.innerText="test123";
```

**EDIT 1**

Updating the structure as requested by @rabsom

```
<div class="q-box qu-pb--small" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
   <div class="q-box qu-cursor--pointer dom_annotate_google_ad" id="div-gpt-ad-1633993162946-0-init-a" style="box-sizing: border-box;" data-google-query-id="CNy0k-Dxiv8CFYCFZgId2jkKvA">
      <div id="google_ads_iframe_/21680945556/li_stick_home_and_ad_react_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 300px; height: 250px;">
        <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://515625e180dff516c1055c5fa3af1b19.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-40/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/21680945556/li_stick_home_and_ad_react_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="300" height="250" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" role="region" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" data-google-container-id="1" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm able to use the `googletag` now. However, it shows up after the ads have been loaded. So, I wait for the DOM to be loaded completely.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
        for (i = 0; i < googletag.pubads().getSlots().length; i++) {
            var slotDomId = googletag.pubads().getSlots()[i].getSlotElementId();
            document.getElementById(slotDomId).innerHTML = '<h1>yourcustomInnerHTML</h1>';
        }
    }
});
```

I try the above code, but even after the DOM has been loaded, it shows `googletag` as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Ad Manager served ads, you do :

```
for(i=0;i<googletag.pubads().getSlots().length;i++) {
 var slotDomId = googletag.pubads().getSlots()[i].getSlotElementId();
 document.getElementById(slotDomId).innerHTML = 'yourcustomInnerHTML';
}
```

Related documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference?hl=fr#googletag.Slot_getSlotElementId).

Note that this method is only available for sites using the Google Publisher Tag (Google Ad Manager library).
For Adsense, you could use the following (assuming the Adsense slots are integrated within a parent div) :

```
var adsenseBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('ins.adsbygoogle');
for(i=0;i<adsenseBlocks.length;i++) {
 var slotDomId = adsenseBlocks[i].parentNode.id
 document.querySelector('#'+ slotDomId).innerHTML = 'yourcustomInnerHTML';
}
```

**EDIT**

Regarding your need to run it from a Chrome extension, you have to inject the script into the tab DOM to get the objects rendered values.

Here is a way to do so :

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "Your Extension Name",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "blablabla",
  "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webNavigation",
        "scripting"
    ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["pageScript.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }]
}
```

*service-worker.js*

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  
function insertScript() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('pageScript.js');
    s.onload = function() { this.remove(); };
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}

  chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
      {
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        func : insertScript
      });
  });

});
```

*pageScript.js*

```
function customHTML() {
   for (i = 0; i < googletag.pubads().getSlots().length; i++) {
        var slotDomId = googletag.pubads().getSlots()[i].getSlotElementId();
        document.getElementById(slotDomId).innerHTML = '<h1>yourcustomInnerHTML</h1>';
      }
    }
    
 //add GPT eventlisteners to detect refresh & lazyloaded ads
 googletag.pubads().addEventListener("slotOnload", (event) => {
      const slot = event.slot;
      customHTML();
    });
```

Comment: Tried this on Quora.com. The `adsenseBlocks` var returned empty list.

Comment: looks like Quora is delivering adsense ads through Google Ad Manager. Try using the first method ;) (i edited the answer so it will work properly now )

Comment: As expected `Uncaught ReferenceError: googletag is not defined`. How should we be initializing `googletag`?

Comment: ^^^Tried it on console.

Comment: it is working on my side.. which country are you trying this from ? Maybe there is a different setup than here... Just tried it right now from FR and it worked just fine.

Comment: I'm from India. Tried a proxy from France. Still has the same error. Don't we need to initialize `googletag`?

Comment: googletag is initialized from the GPT library. as long as you wait for the ads to be downloaded, it should be available.. Make sure you dont have any adblock extension activated on your browser. Did you accept the cookies from the domain ? Do you see ads ? If yes, could you inspect and share its structure ?

Comment: Yes, I do see the ads. I've updated the question with the HTML structure. Pls have a look.

Comment: Ok. I'm able to use the `googletag` now. Honestly, no idea what changed. Initially also, I was waiting for the ads to be displayed, and then only I was trying to use the `googletag`. But, I'm glad that it has now worked.

Comment: Now, I'm trying to do it programmatically, ie waiting for the DOM to be completely loaded. I'm encountering the same error. `googletag` is undefined. Is loading of ads a part of the complete loading of DOM?
I've updated the question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253784/discussion-between-rabsom-and-praful-bagai).

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the complete solution @rabsom. It worked like a charm. Just a few things, which are a bit buggy. (1) The ads load again after some time, replacing my customHTML. (2) This script finds all the googletags at once. On a lazily loaded page, it does not works.

Comment: For both of these solutions, I'm using your `pageScript.js` code inside `setinterval`. It solves both of the above stated problems. However, I'm unsure whether it's the right way to solve this problem or not. Any comments here?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different tags that i am aware of.

There is a class called **adsbygoogle**. You can access how it is added statically in to the html file with [this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9190028?hl=en) link.

Other than that i have seen other websites use ids start with **google_ads**. In order to get all ids you can use;

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[id*="google"]').forEach(el=>{
        //your code here
})
```

Keep in mind that this will return the container div and the iframe tag as well.

Comment: Tried this on Quora.com. Couldn't find `google_ads` div

Comment: Can you try the code i just edited. Please try it on console first since you may not see the divs with the injected script since they can render before your code runs. We can find another solution to make it work in your injceted script if you confirm this works on your end.